# Como Manter os valores de uma variável, mesmo reiniciando o programa, em Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, variáveis

Estou com os seguintes problemas, toda vez em que eu crio um programa em Javascript e declaro os valores das variáveis, **ao reiniciar o programa o valor da variável se perde**. ex:

```
var usuario = {
      nome: "Eduardo Ribeiro";
      idade: 19 }
```

ao reiniciar o programa, (abrir e fechar) os valores das variáveis são perdidos, eu meio que teria que adicionar novamente cada valor, eu queria saber como eu faço para não reiniciar os valores das variáveis ao fechar o programa, se a resposta for munto longa, poderiam me indicar algum algo para que eu possa estudar, pois sou iniciante na areá e não consegui achar procurando na net...

Comment: Eduardo, já pensou em persistir esses valores?

Comment: Para respostas longas, sugiro usar um message broker como o kafka. Para manter os valores salvos das variáveis, você pode salvá-las no banco de dados e carregá-las durante a inicialização do servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca como a [`cacache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacache) para salvar informações via chave-valor. Por exemplo:

```
const cacache = require('cacache');

cacache.put('caminho-para-meu-arquivo', 'teste', '1');
```

E para ler a informação base iniciar lendo direto do `cache`:

```
cache.get('caminho-para-meu-arquivo', 'teste').then(console.log); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o LocalStorage, ele armazena os dados até que o sistema altere/remova ou seja feito de forma manual.

caso tenha interesse em usar, neste site você consegue mais informações:
https://tableless.com.br/guia-f%C3%A1cil-sobre-usar-localstorage-com-javascript/